# Как объединить несколько .txt-файлов в 1 файл?

Tags: linux, bash

имеется около 50 файлов. В каждом файле имеется овер-много строк. Необходимо из всех этих файлов сделать 1 большой файл. Было так:

file1.txt

```
44rr-rsr
45rr-rsr
46rr-rsr
```

file2.txt

```
5tt.lvn
5mf.ubg
6hg.gnn
```

Необходимо получить так:

file3.txt

```
44rr-rsr
45rr-rsr
46rr-rsr
5tt.lvn
5mf.ubg
6hg.gnn
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

самое логичное — воспользоваться программой *cat*:

```
$ cat *.txt > файл.с.результатом
```

Comment: Блин, загуглил http://pingvinus.ru/note/concatenate-files-cat-command, посмотрел, думал надо писать название файлов) Не подумал. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Находим через `find` по шаблону все файлы в текущей директории и через аргумент `-exec` выполняем вывод содержимого с помощью команды `cat`, далее направляем STDOUT поток в файл. Например так:

```
find ./* -type f -maxdepth 0 -name "file*.txt" -exec cat {} \; > output.txt
```

P.S. Будьте аккуратны и не уйдите в рекурсию. Если ваш файл `output.txt` попадет под шаблон `"file*.txt"` у вас будет бесконечно выполнятся команда

Comment: Спасибо! Работает, но только так: find ./ -type f -name "*.txt" -exec cat {} \; > output.txt

Comment: Не знаю, насколько бесконечно, но содержимое всех .txt объединяется в output.txt

Comment: @misdeed понятное дело, что будет работать. `file*.txt` это был шаблон названия ваших файлов `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`. Я вам советую или выходной файл в другое место сохранять, или по шаблону искать файлы, иначе в следующий раз запуская эту команду попадете в рекурсию